# Postgres Database in Dockerfile

Tags: database, postgresql, docker

I am trying to build a PostgreSQL image in DockerManually becuase I need to add some certain configuration for the database that doesnot exit in the postgres images provided with docker. 
I wrote the following dockerfile

```
    FROM alpine:3.7

    #update the OS
    RUN apk update

    #installing alpine software kit
    RUN apk add alpine-sdk

RUN apk update \
  postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGISV \
  postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGISV-scripts \
  postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-pgrouting \
  postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-pgrouting-scripts \
  postgresql-server-dev-$PG_MAJOR

#installing postgresql
RUN apk add postgresql
RUN apk add openrc --no-cache

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .base_deps build-base openssl-dev zlib-dev libxml2-dev wget gnupg ca-certificates
RUN apk add --no-cache readline-dev glib-lang libssl1.0 postgresql postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update binutils
RUN apk add --no-cache sudo
RUN apk --purge del .base_deps
RUN echo "postgres ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/postgres
RUN chmod 600 /etc/sudoers.d/postgres
RUN sync
#RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start
#RUN postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data


EXPOSE 5432
```

then I am trying to lunch the dockerfile with interactive shell with

docker run -it processID

then the follwoing command to instantite database

```
 initdb Database
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locales
  COLLATE:  C
  CTYPE:    C.UTF-8
  MESSAGES: C
  MONETARY: C
  NUMERIC:  C
  TIME:     C
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory Database ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default timezone ... UTC
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... sh: locale: not found
2019-11-18 08:04:06.670 UTC [89] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success.
```

Then I am trying to lunch the database using the following command

```
postgres -D Database
2019-11-18 08:05:27.358 UTC [91] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-11-18 08:05:27.358 UTC [91] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address not available
2019-11-18 08:05:27.358 UTC [91] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2019-11-18 08:05:27.360 UTC [91] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
2019-11-18 08:05:27.360 UTC [91] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I am getting some errors I do not know exactly why? any help would really be appreciated.

I did switch yo docker-compose, and here is an example of the file

```
version: "3"
services:
  #  Create a service named db.
  db:
    #   Use the Docker Image postgres. This will pull the newest release.
    image: "postgres:12.1-alpine"
    #   Give the container the name my_postgres. You can changes to something else.
    container_name: "theNameOfDockerCompose"
    #   Setup the username, password, and database name. You can changes these values.
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=DatabaseName
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password
      - POSTGRES_DB=development
    #   Maps port 54320 (localhost) to port 5432 on the container. You can change the ports to fix your needs.
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    #   Set a volume some that database is not lost after shutting down the container.
    #   I used the name postgres-data but you can changed it to something else.
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

This is file is what I am using now. 
But with Dockerfile, I still cannot enable the endpoints to access the dataBase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgres-docker-bind-address-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890233/postgresql-docker-could-not-bind-ipv6-socket-cannot-assign-requested-address/52381997)

Comment: I don't think this is a `bind_address` issue.  Instead, this is an issue where two postmasters are running on the same port.  Please check `ps -ef` to see where postgres is already running--you may need to change `port` to another value (besides 5432) in `Database/postgresql.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate of [postgres-docker-bind-address-ipv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890233/postgresql-docker-could-not-bind-ipv6-socket-cannot-assign-requested-address/52381997)

update `listen_addresses = '*'` into `postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`

Comment: The file postgresql/data/postgresql.conf dose not exist

Comment: Check in /etc/postgresql folder.  Log into the container and look for it.  If you find it then you need to supply the edited file from dockerfile copy Command and run it

Answer (score 0):

```
2019-11-18 08:05:27.360 UTC [91] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
```

points to a missing folder. Add

```
RUN mkdir -p /run/postgresql
```

to your Dockerfile

In addition, you need to change the `listen_addresses = "*"` in your `postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`. Otherwise, your database will be bound to localhost in your container and you will not be able to access it from anywhere except within that particular container. You can see that in your logs here

```
2019-11-18 08:05:27.358 UTC [91] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
```

for the localhost binding. In addition, this will fix the following error message in your log

```
2019-11-18 08:05:27.358 UTC [91] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address not available
```

in which postgres failed to the bind for ipv6.

Comment: The file postgresql/data/postgresql.conf dose not exist

Comment: Have you tried `find` to search the folder structure for it? The full path to `postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` might be different based on your installation

Comment: then you can use the example config provided by postgres: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample

Comment: @Osama Sy if any of the answers solved your issue please accept the appropriate answer to share the resolution with the community. If not please provide further information

Comment: None of these solved my issue, I still not able to figure out the dataBase is not working from Docker file, So I switched to Docker Compose

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Can you update your question with your current work and error such that we can help resolve the issue?

Comment: I did update the post with the docker-compose file that I am running now. That should not cause any problem for me because I read all the default configuration for that they have and it seems fine for my project at this point, but I still need to figure something out for the docker file, as I need to set up specific configuration later.

Comment: @OsamaSy please check your logs. If your configuration and logs in the question are up to date you still have the localhost issue. Or did you update the postgres config file and put it in your `./postgres-data` folder? Could you share that file in your question as well